# want to search a numeric value in given string in python

Tags: python

```
string3 = "abc 123 $$%%"

list1 = string3.split()
print(list1)
for i in list1:
    if int(i) > 0:
        print("it's a number")
    else:
        print("not a number")
```

Getting below error :

```
if int(i) > 0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

Comment: What do you think `int('$$%%')` should return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> str = "abc 123 $$%%"
>>> [int(s) for s in str.split() if s.isdigit()]
[123]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `i.isdigit()`

```
string3 = "abc 123 $$%%"

list1 = string3.split() 
print(list1)
for i in list1:
    if i.isdigit():
        print("it's a number") 
    else: 
        print("not a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fancy way:

```
>>> s = "abc 123 $$%%"
>>> map(int,filter(str.isdigit,s.split()))
[123]
```

Explanation:

- `s.split()` is splitting the string on spaces and generates: `['abc', '123', '$$%%']`
- `str.isdigit` is a function which returns `True` if all characters in the argument are digits.
- `filter` filters out elements of a list which do not pass the test. First 
  argument is the test function: `str.isdigit`, second argument is the list.
- Finally, `map` transforms one list to another. First argument is the transform function `int`, second argument is the list found from `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
string3 = "abc 123 $$%%"

list1 = string3.split()
print(list1)
for i in list1:
    if i.isdigit():
        print("it's a number")
    else:
        print("not a number")
```

**Output**:
['abc', '123', '$$%%']
not a number
it's a number
not a number

Answer (score 0):

```
string3 = "abc 123 $$%%"

list1 = string3.split()
print(list1)
for i in list1:
    try:
        int(i)
        print("It is a number")
    except ValueError:
        print("It is not a number")
```

Try this code